# onclick link modification using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using the code below to change a href to an onclick:

```
$('.sidenav li a').each(function() {
     var href = $(this).attr('href');
     $(this).attr('onclick', href)
       .removeAttr('href');
});
```

This does the job however I can not work out how to change the onclick function attached to it. It currently takes the href link and applkies it to the onlick e.g. `onclick="https://stackoverflow.com/"`

If anyone has any idea how this could be changed that would be great!

Thanks - Scott

Comment: NO need to pass.Better add event in dom.Tell me what type of function you have?

Comment: It's easy enough to do what you want (set the attribute to `"window.location="+href`). But I can't help but wonder WHY you are doing this? There's probably a better way to solve the underlying problem, but you don't tell us what that is.

Answer (score 1):

I Don't know this would help you or not but you can try this.

```js
$(".sidenav li a").each(function() {
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $(this).attr('onclick', `print(${JSON.stringify(href)})`)
    .removeAttr('href');
});

function print(href) {
  console.log('Clicked on', href);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sidenav">
  <li>
    <a href="http://example.com">Test</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

`onclick` needs some JavaScript in string form. The solution of harshad narkhede should work just fine. However, I wonder if it really is what you want. More on that later.

To answer your question, you probably want to add an event listener to the DOM element directly instead of changing the `onclick` attribute:

```js
$('.sidenav li a').each(function() {
  const el = $(this);
  const href = el.attr('href');
  el[0].addEventListener('click', () => location.replace(href));
  el.removeAttr('href');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sidenav">
  <li>
    <a href="http://example.com">test</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

You could do this even without jQuery:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav li a').forEach((el) => {
  const href = el.getAttribute('href');
  el.addEventListener('click', () => location.replace(href));
  el.removeAttribute('href');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sidenav">
  <li>
    <a href="http://example.com">test</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**However, I wonder if you really want to do that.** You could easily just prevent the click and do whatever you want with the `href`. Consider the following:

```js
document.querySelector('.sidenav').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  // Check if we are clicking on an <a> tag
  if (event.target.tagName !== 'A') {
    return;
  }
  
  // Prevent the actual click and the navigation away from the current page
  event.preventDefault();
  // Get and print the href of the link we clicked on
  console.log('Clicked on', event.target.getAttribute('href'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sidenav">
  <li>
    <a href="http://example.com">test</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```